# backbone.js each function not receiving the models

Tags: backbone.js

I am trying to receive a json data and append to element. all are work fine up to i use the static assignments. while i start to fetch the data from server side, or using fetch nothing work for me.. something wrong with my fech process, any can help me to correct my fetch process and update my code.(instead of simply placing the correct code)..

my JSON(sample):

```
nameing = [
    {name:'student4'},
    {name:'student5'},
    {name:'student6'}
]
```

Backbone code:

```
(function($){

var list = {};

list.model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults:{
    name:'need the name'
  }
});



list.collect = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model:list.model,
  url : 'data/names.json', //this is correct path.
  initialize:function(){
    this.fetch();
  }
});


list.view = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize:function(){
    this.collection = new list.collect();
    this.collection.on("reset", this.render, this);
  },
  render:function(){
    _.each(this.collection.models, function(data){
      console.log(data); // i am not get any model here... any one correct my code?  
    })
  }
});

var newView = new list.view();


})(jQuery)
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is not valid. [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)

```
[
  {"name":"student4"},
  {"name":"student5"},
  {"name":"student6"}
]
```

Comment: yes 100% you are correct, thanks a lot... you saved me a huge time. now it works fine.